Launched a Shopify Public APP need assitance with Managed Pricing
Launched a Shopify Public APP with Managed Pricing in Shopify, check screenshot below:

Now the problem is that APP is being installed without charging subscription fees of the app.
When I access following URL:
https://admin.shopify.com/store/{store_handle}/charges/{app_handle}/pricing_plans

It takes me to the pricing page, check screenshot below:

How can I show this page before my APP page loads? And check if merchant has subscribed or not?
Documentation link: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/launch/billing/managed-pricing

Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79005672/how-to-redirect-users-to-shopify-plan-page-in-a-shopify-app-using-remix?rq=2 trying to implement it
